# How to let ImageView dictate size of custom Drawable?

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

Im working on a initials drawable, sort of like gmail has.
**I want this drawable to scale automatically to image view size** (which will be hardcoded in xml, but multiple variants), therefore I dont want the initials drawable to have hardcoded size as well, which is to me seems is what getIntrinsicWidth() does.

Is there a way to do this? Is there way then for drawable to get the image view size, to do its calculations for rendering?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Vector drawables can scale automatically by default. Setting `android:width="24dp"` for example in your drawable xml doesn't force it to be this size, it's just a default value.

Set the `ImageView` to the size you want, and set your drawable as the image resource. It will fill the available space.

In layout xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"/>
```

Or in java:

```
ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);
```

Mess with `android:scaleType` if you want different crop behavior.

Comment: I was thinkimg custom drawable subclass which uses canvas calls.